# Ошибка конкатенации в скрипте FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

FastReport 4.14.
В событие `OnBeforePrint` объекта `Memo1` добавляю код:

```
Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + 'Some text';
```

В отчете выводится только `Memo1.Text`, прим этом если текст добавлять в начало строки:

```
Memo1.Text := 'Some text' + Memo1.Text;
```

то выводится полная строка, как и хотелось. Кто знает почему?

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, что текст в `Memo1.Text` оканчивается на символ перевода строки. Если добавлять текст в конец, то текст окажется на следующей строке, и если у `Memo1` нет свойства "Растягиваемый" / "StretchMode", то он покажет только столько строк, сколько влезает по высоте.

Comment: Для добавления в конец строки можно воспользоваться следущим способом:  
`Memo1.Text := Memo1.Memo[0] + 'Some text';`